# MSCRM 2011 Online - Soap with Javascript or PHP

Tags: php, javascript, web-services, dynamics-crm

I am trying to access a MSCRM 2011 online and, I need a way to comunicate with it (through webservices) from javascript or php.

What I need to do is basically, login an create a contact or an account.

So, what I need is the full description of the soap XML, so I can forge it in a string myself.

But, the main problem is that I can not find an XML example for, loggin in to a MSCRM 2011 online, and access to a entity webmethod (like, Create(), for instance)

Could you give me some advices or directions???

Comment: May be the question is not clear enough. ??? =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can use MSCRM SOAP methods for Create, they are for retrieve (unless you build your own - e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg594434.aspx).

Instead use the standard CRM OData methods to Create/Update.  There are plenty of examples in the SDK - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334427.aspx

Thanks
Glenn

Comment: The CrmService description has Create() Retrieve() RetrieveMultiple() Update() Delete() as webmethods.
Why do you said that??

Comment: Sorry.  You can do it, but you'll be hand constructing the SOAP Execute body.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg594434.aspx - shows how you can use the SOAPLogger tool in the MSCRM 2011 SDK to get the format of the SOAP messages (example provided in the link is AssignRequest).

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a simple example in PHP of how to connect to dynamics 2011 online. Might be of use.

https://github.com/Ben-Speakman/PHP-Dynamics-Online-CRM-2011-SOAP-Class